# Query with multiple joins plus junction table

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, union

I'm working with this query and struggling a bit. The joins make sense to me but getting the data out of the `images` table which has a junction table called `user_image` is escaping me.

```
SELECT c.id, c.city, ROUND(( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(27.9861) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
* cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-80.6628) ) + sin( radians(27.9861) ) * sin(radians(lat)) ) ),0) AS distance, t.id, t.name, t.price, t.duration, d.description, u.fname, i.image_path, i.image_name
FROM city c
    JOIN trip t ON c.id = t.city_id
    JOIN trip_description d ON t.id = d.trip_id
    JOIN user u ON t.user_id = u.id
    -- Need to get all images that match trip and is_main = 1
HAVING distance < 20 
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0 , 45;
```

My image tables look like this...

- user_image: user_id | trip_id | image_id
- image: id | image_name | is_active | is_main

Not sure if I'm supposed to be using another join, a union, a query in a query?

Comment: In my original question, I tried to simplify the query and that was probably not a good idea, so I changed it to include the actual query I'm trying to get working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I got it. Thanks to everyone who responded.

```
SELECT c.id, c.city, ROUND(( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(27.9861) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
* cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-80.6628) ) + sin( radians(27.9861) ) * sin(radians(lat)) ) ),0) AS distance, t.id, t.name, t.price, t.duration, d.description, u.fname, i.path, i.name
FROM city c
    JOIN trip t ON c.id = t.city_id
    JOIN trip_description d ON t.id = d.trip_id
    JOIN user u ON t.user_id = u.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user_image ui ON ui.trip_id = t.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN image i ON ui.image_id = i.id
    AND i.main=1
HAVING distance < 20 
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0 , 45;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for all image names from a given user, that match `is_main = 1` and `is_active = 1`:

```
SELECT c.id as city_id, c.city, u.fname, t.name, d.description, i.image_name
FROM image i
    LEFT JOIN user_image ui ON ui.image_id = i.id 
    LEFT JOIN user u ON u.id = ui.user_id
    LEFT JOIN trip t ON t.id = ui.trip_id
    LEFT JOIN trip_description d ON t.id = d.trip_id
    LEFT JOIN city c ON c.id = t.city_id
WHERE u.id = 1
    AND i.is_main = 1
    AND i.active = 1
ORDER BY c.id;
```

Comment: Note that `LEFT JOIN user u...WHERE u.id = 1` is the same as `INNER JOIN u`

Comment: I'm not very good at this stuff, so am struggling to understand why the rest of the query was changed? In my original question I tried to simplify the query so I could maybe better understand it, but now that I see your answer I have no idea how to apply that to the actually query I need to get working. Maybe I'll change my question to include it and you can take a look. Thanks for the quick response btw.

Comment: Oh and actually it's all image names from a given 'trip', not user.

Comment: I need to better understand your database structure. If I am correct, there is a trip table. The trip is linked to 1 city. The trip can have several descriptions (if only one, why is it not in the same table?). The trip is linked to 1 user. Several images can then be linked to the trip using the matching table user_image. Can an image be in several trips? or can a image be linked to several users? If both answers are no, you should merge the 2 image tables into a single table with trip_id |  image_name | is_active | is_main. Please detail the structure & i should be able to help.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help with this, I really appreciate it. The reason that the trip description is not in the same table is because I read that it's better to have LARGE amounts of text in a separate table. The description could be quite large. Several images can be linked to a trip, AND those same images could be linked to different trips. I was hoping to have a single images table for trips and users, but now I'm starting to wonder if that is even possible.

Comment: Regarding the description, you could use a TEXT column, it is actually stored outside of the table:  "Each BLOB or TEXT value is represented internally by a separately allocated object." (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html). Regarding the structure, I understand the trip - image link. But if an image is linked to a single user, the user_id should be in the image table, not the user_image table. And you could rename that last table into trip_image. I'll update my answer when the table structure is definitive.

Comment: Thank you for your time Nicolas. I could put the description in the trip table, that's not a problem. I understand now that the junction table shouldn't have both user_id and trip_id in there. HOWEVER, there is not a one to one relationship for user and image. A user could have multiple images, not for this particular query though. I'm guessing I need 2 junction tables, one for trips and one for users?

Comment: Anyway, still trying to get this particular query to work correctly so anything you could do to help would be much appreicated. I did get it to kind of work by adding two more joins, one for the junction table to the trip table and one of the image table to the junction table, however it ONLY returns a result IF there is an image and that's not what I want.